# Books like Rudin PMA

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, set-theory

Personally, I really love Rudin's PMA style books. Now I am finding books on point-set topology and set theory, so I can review these topics quickly. I also like exercises from baby rudin, so I want these books to have (not too many) challenging problems.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you be precise of what do you want? I think you want reference books on set theory and point set topology to refer to concepts if I got you right

Comment: Maybe _Set Theory for the Working Mathematician_ by Ciesielski? I forget it if has exercises though. I first learned axiomatic set theory from the appendix of Kelley's _General Topology_, which is quite Rudin-like: it is flawlessly clear and extremely concise, and does have exercises, but I can't really recommend that because it is not ZF set theory.

Comment: @ManthaSaiGopal I am not finding concise and compact books on these topics, targeting one exposed to these topics before. Challenging exercises are important too.

Comment: I think you want to refer to these topics as part of Real Analysis course(If you are looking to get deep into these topics I am not aware of any books). Invariably in any real analysis course one has to learn some set theory and point set topology so you can refer to analysis books for that. My favorites are Analysis I and II by Terence Tao and Introduction to Real Analysis by Robert G Bartle.